# Should I repeat product number in ecomm_prodid for cart (Google Dynamic Remarketing)

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

With Google Dynamic Remarketing, if I have a product twice in my cart, should I enter the product number twice in the "ecomm_prodid" property? Exemple :

```
var google_tag_params = { 
  ecomm_prodid: [111, 111, 222, 333]
};
```

If YES, for the "ecomm_totalvalue" property, should I enter the total amount of the 4 products or just the total amount of distinct product?

I hope my question is clear.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You just want this ids to later make dynamic remarketing to your customers, so you don't need to enter twice, because you are going to show them anyway.